# MS word 2007 page N of M

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, page-numbers

I want to add a "Page N of M" field in word 2007 (where M is the total number of pages and N is the current page).

This sounds like something that should already be built-in, but I can't find it.
Where can I find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply go to the `Insert` tab and select either `Header` or `Footer`.

From here, select `Page Number`, and simply format it to however you want.

Comment: Thanks, I found that there was a scrollbar in the list of formats available and found the one I want there.

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable or install the "Building Blocks" template, which will then have that format included as a numbering option for you to choose.

Here is a complete set of instructions.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/i-don-t-see-galleries-of-page-numbers-headers-and-footers-cover-pages-or-equations-HA010203346.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP001226513

I linked to that from here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-and-format-page-numbers-HP001226513.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933312

Comment: To the downvoter, you can assume that since the questioner said she could not find it, and it is in an obvious place, that it may not exist on her system. It does not show on my two copies of Word 2007 by default.

Comment: Or Word 2010...